# How do I access the remaining fields of Parse's User (PFUser) Object?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm trying to access the balance of the data fields of the current user.

The following is what I can only see when querying the currentUser in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po currentUser
<PFUser: 0x17642d80, objectId: FUsro30ZFu, localId: (null)> {
    displayName = Turkey;
    email = "frederick.c.lee@gmail.com";
    firstName = Frederick;
    lastName = Lee;
    username = "UncleRic ";
}
```

Here's the field (as other) that I want to get:
[image]

These are the unsuccessful attempts:

```
(lldb) po currentUser["location"]
error: indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'const char *' is not an Objective-C pointer
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po currentUser.location
error: property 'location' not found on object of type 'PFUser *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po currentUser.valueForKey("location")
error: property 'valueForKey' not found on object of type 'PFUser *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

What is the correct method for accessing the remainder fields of the object 'PFUser'?

Also, how do I update/assign a field value of PFUser?

Apparently I need to recast a String into an AnyObject object.  But the 'location' field has already been defined as a String field.

[image]

Comment: what Parse table is "`latLon`", "`location`" and "`middleName`" *really* living on, if not PFUser?

Comment: use objectForKey: and setObject:forKey:

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here.

1) I was attempting to user Swift instead of Objective-C in the debugger.

 So I got the syntax all screwed up.

2) I didn't restart (cold start) my app @ device after I changed my parse.com data on-line (via web).  So I was looking a latent (non refreshed data).

The following is the correct format of looking at a PFUser attribute value:

```
(lldb) po [currentUser objectForKey:@"firstName"]
Frederick

(lldb) po [currentUser objectForKey:@"location"]
Ann Arbor
```

Here's the  correct Swift syntax for updating the PFUser object.  *Note: be sure to have the actual SAVE() done on a backend thread.*

The code user is essentially of proof-of-concept that I can actually update the file.

```
func updateParseUser(newUser:User, sender:UIViewController) {

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if ((currentUser) == nil) {
        return
    }

    if let revisedlocation = newUser.location {
        currentUser?.setValue(revisedlocation, forKey: "location")
    }

    if let phone = newUser.phoneNumber {
        currentUser?.setValue(phone, forKey: "phone")
    }

    currentUser!.save()

}
```

Thanks for the feedback